# If $A$ is similar to $B$, is there only one and only one $S$ that satisfies $S^{-1}AS=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So the definition of similarity states that if $A$ is similar to $B$ there exists such an $S$ that satisfies $S^{-1}AS=B$. But is there only one $S$? And in general, how would one solve for $S$?

Comment: No. If $S$ satisfies $S^{-1}AS=B$, then $kS$ too for all $k\neq 0$ in $K$

Comment: As an explicit counterexample, we know that $I$ is similar to itself, but literally *any* invertible $S$ satisfies $S^{-1}IS=I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, $S$ is not unique.

One possible way to find one such $S$, is to find a canonical form to transform it to.

For example if the matrix is diagonalizable.

then from finding eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$ and let them be the columns of $P$ and $Q$ respectively, then

$$P^{-1}AP=D=Q^{-1}BQ$$

then

$$QP^{-1}APQ^{-1}=B$$

Then $S=PQ^{-1}.$

However, not every matrix is diagonalizable. In that case, Jordan canonical form might be a potential candidate to transform to.